# What happens if dd encounters errors while output of dd is being piped to gzip?

Tags: linux, backup, dd, stdout, stderr

Suppose that

```
dd if=/dev/sda bs=100M | gzip -c > somefile.img.gz
```

is done. If errors occur in `dd`, do I get to see error messages in terminal, or do they get ignored?

Also, suppose that `dd` encounters a read error. Will `dd` just skip the block, or will it print out error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see the error message if there is any.

There are different types of read errors and `dd` should always report it. If the error is continuable, `dd` just outputs nulls for that block. Otherwise dd will stop.

If you want to recover data, `ddrescue` is more error-tolerant than `dd`.

Comment: I realized that my new post may have been a duplicate, so I am commenting here. What I want is if dd encounters bad sectors of hard disk, does it send an error message to terminal, or does it just ignore it? That's my question. Sorry for messing up with questions.

Comment: dd will send an error to the terminal (STDERR) whenever it encounters a bad block.